# assimp wrong texture file name

Tags: 3d

I am using assimp to load a model for opengl. But I used following methods to get the texture file name.

```
aiReturn texFound = scene->mMaterials[m]->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, texIndex, &path);
```

but the filename store in path is wrong. Some times it appends \ in the front of the filename. ex. \super_diffuse.tga. Actually the filename is super_diffuse.tga.

Is there a way to solve it or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

How about you simply write a function that removes the backslash if it's there?
You'll need an absolute path (or relative to your exe) to your texture file anyway.

And no, I don't think this is a bug, because that's the path stored in the model file. Assimp has nothing to do with it.
Also I have never experienced your problem.

Comment: Indeed, assimp does not attempt at changing the paths it reads.